# A html string is escaped in haml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

```
#test
  - html = "<a href='http://www.a.com'>Test</a>"
  = html
```

The output is

```
<div id='test'>
  &lt;a href='http://www.a.com'&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
</div>
```

But I want a output:

```
<div id='test'>
  <a href='http://www.a.com'>Test</a>
</div>
```

Anyone has solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
= raw html
```

or:

```
= html.html_safe
```

Comment: `html_safe` only works for strings, that's why I prefer `!=` (see @james-chen's answer below or `raw`.

Comment: Is there a notable difference between `= raw html`, `= html.html_safe`, and `!= html`? **Edit:** [This question covers some differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251284/raw-vs-html-safe-vs-h-to-unescape-html).

Answer (score 35):

haml also provides with its equivalent tag to rails 3's **raw** method: **!=**, eg:

!= html

Answer (score 6):

There was a change in rails 3 so that all content is now html escaped by default. See [this blog post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/) from Yehuda Katz for more details.

In order to print the html directly you need to use html_safe on your variable:

```
#content
 .title
   %h1= @title
   = @content.html_safe
```

For a more complex example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795926/unescaping-inline-links-in-haml/3796011#3796011) to a similar question.